# Trouble finding correct basis of subspace defined with a linear equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following subspace in R^3 : H = {(X,Y,Z) in R^3 | x + 2y − z = 0 }
When I try to solve,
I express z = x + 2y which implies that (X,Y,X+2Y).

I then find my basis as follows
T(e1) = T(1 0 0) = (1 0 1)
T(e2) = T(0 1 0) = (0 1 2)

So my basis is v1 = (1 0 1) and v2 = (0 1 2) but the correct answer for v2 is (2 -1 0)

I do not understand why. **If basis is not unique I want to know how to find (2 -1 0).**

Comment: Basis is not unique!

Comment: A basis is not unique! Note that $v_3=(2,-1,0)=2v_1-v_2$, so $(v_1, v_3)$ and $(v_2, v_3)$ are also bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space consists of all vectors orthogonal to $\mathbf n = (1,2,-1)^T$, (why?) so any two linearly-independent vectors orthogonal to $\mathbf n$ form a basis for it. Without further constraints there’s no good reason to call one choice more “correct” than another.

Now, as to how to come up with $(2,-1,0)^T$ specifically, I would first suggest following whatever method your text demonstrated for solving similar problems. However, for any nonzero vector $\mathbf v = (a,b,c)^T$, we also have that the vectors $(0,c,-b)^T$, $(-c,0,a)^T$ and $(b,-a,0)^T$ are all orthogonal to $\mathbf v$ and at least two of them are non-zero. (These are just the cross products of $\mathbf v$ with the standard basis vectors.) For $\mathbf v=(1,2,-1)^T$, the last one just happens to be $(2,-1,0)^T$.